# Rejection Method Generating Cauchy variables

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, simulation

$$f(x)=\frac{e^x}{(1+e^x)^2}$$    $$g(x)=\frac{1}{2}e^{-\left | x \right |}$$  both for ($-\infty$$<x<$$\infty$).Why we can't use either f or g to sample from a Cauchy distribution.  What's the reason for that ??And also  whether either would provide a practically useful way of generating standard normal
random variables???
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are constants $K_i$ such that $K_1f(x) \ge \varphi(x)$ and $K_2g(x) \ge \varphi(x),$ where $\varphi$ is the standard normal PDF. However, neither $f$ nor $g$ similarly 'majorizes' the Cauchy PDF because of the Cauchy's 'fat' tails.// If there is more to your question, please edit it to clarify.

Comment: For example with $g$ (Laplace), see [_this post_](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1635250/what-are-numerical-methods-of-evaluating-p1-z-leq-2-for-standard-normal-z/1635264#1635264) under 'umbrella' heading.