# Simulate a random variable by the given density

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

> Given is the density $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
> \frac{3}{4}\left(2x-x^2\right)&\mbox{if }x \in (0,2) \\ 
> 0&\mbox{else}\end{cases}$$
>
> Find a random variable for the density.

There are probably several methods for doing this but I only know of inverse transform and I like to try to use it here.

Firstly, we need the distribution function of the density. It is (just assume this is correct):

$$F(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{3}{4}x^2-\frac{1}{4}x^3&\mbox{if }0<x\leq 2 \\
1 &\mbox{if }x>2\\ 
0 &\mbox{if }x<0\end{cases}$$

Now we need to inverse this distribution function:
$$y=\frac{3}{4}x^2-\frac{1}{4}x^3$$

I used a software for this one because it got very complicated when I tried to do it by hand :(

$$x= \sqrt[3]{2\sqrt{y^2-y}-2y+1}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2\sqrt{y^2-y}-2y+1}}$$

While the other party of the distribution function didn't need any change except for the cases, so for the inverse we have

$$F^{-1}(y)=\begin{cases} \sqrt[3]{2\sqrt{y^2-y}-2y+1}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2\sqrt{y^2-y}-2y+1}}&\mbox{if }\\
1 &\mbox{if }\\ 
0 &\mbox{if }\end{cases}$$

I didn't expect it will end up that complicated, I don't even know what cases I need to use and how the inverse of $0$ will be treated as it doesn't seem to be defined : /

Maybe there is an easier way of solving the problem or did I miss an important step / did a mistake somewhere? :s

Comment: What do you mean by "Find a random variable for the density."?

Comment: I think that show who is $F$ is sufficient, because $F$ is a probability distribution, so $X$ is a r.v. such that $\mathbb{P}(X \le x)=F(x)$

Comment: @MostafaAyaz By that I mean "Simulate a random variable by the given density". I thought I could do it with inversion method. But as I tried above, it didn't go well : /

Comment: @Skills Is that really it? :o No further calculations needed?

Comment: You really don't need the "cases".  The cdf has range $[0,1]$, so $[0,1]$ is the domain of the inverse and you needn't consider inputs outside that interval.  Intuitively, you are going to "simulate" $X$ by generating a random number $U$ uniformly in $[0,1]$ and plugging into $F^{-1}$.

Comment: @NateEldredge How do I write all that correctly in maths? Ok, I'm plugging $U$ into my inverse as you recommended: $$X=F^{-1}(U)$$
Then $$F_X(x)=P(X\leq x) = P(F^{-1}(U) \leq x)=P(U \leq F(x))=F(x)$$
?

Comment: Right, that's exactly the idea.

Comment: @NateEldredge Great thanks :) Maybe you can show how the inverse needs to look like? I'm not sure if mine is really right because of these cases. I don't know how they need to look like now :o

Comment: What I'm saying is that there are no cases.  You could just say $F^{-1}(y) = \sqrt[3]{\dots} + \dots$ with the formula you have, assuming the algebra is right.  There's a separate issue that the quantity under the cube root is a complex number (note $y^2 - y < 0$) and it has three cube roots.  If the algebra is right then one of them should be a real number, and that's the value you really want $F^{-1}$ to have.

Comment: I don't know what methods of generating distributions you have studied. The inverse CDF (quantile) approach seems a little messy. // That is (by far) not the only method. Seems a good candidate for an 'acceptance-rejection' method. // Have you noticed the relationship btw your dist'n and BETA(2,2)?

Comment: Perhaps look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1635250/what-are-numerical-methods-of-evaluating-p1-z-leq-2-for-standard-normal-z/1635264#1635264).