# Chi-square probabilities

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, chi-squared

How are the values in chi-square distribution tables derived for different values of $\alpha$ and degrees of freedom, given the PDF? Any help appreciated.

Comment: How could the c.d.f. not be useful for this? Those tables are tables of values of the c.d.f. or its inverse.

Comment: Sorry, meant to ask how the values are derived, given the PDF

Comment: For some values of the 'degrees of freedom' parameter (DF), the CDF can be expr in closed form, and tabled values can be computed by calculus. An exmp is when DF = 2, so that CHISQ(2) is an exponential distribution. Otherwise, numerical integration is the straightforward method. // There are some rational function approximations of the CDF (e.g., truncated series expansions) that are good enough over certain ranges of DFs to give several places of accuracy. // Nowadays, stat software gives v. good values. Exmp: in R `qchisq(.95, 5)` returns 11.0705, where `qchisq` is quantile fcn, inv CDF.

Comment: Maybe see [_Wikipedia_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function) for some details.

Comment: Maybe also, for [more on numerical integration:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1635250/what-are-numerical-methods-of-evaluating-p1-z-leq-2-for-standard-normal-z/1635264#1635264).